# RelaxNG: Define element based on another element

Tags: relaxng

I have a .RNC file where I define all my XML elements, which is compiled into an XSD by `relax ng`.

I have several elements that share many attributes, and it is getting messy with the maintenance... therefore I would like to centralize this info by using/simulating some kind of inheritance.

Let's say I define an element like this:

```
person = element PERSON {
    attribute name { text },
    attribute city { text } 
}
```

Now I would like to extend, something like:

```
employee = element EMPLOYEE extends PERSON {
    attribute company { text }
}
```

Is this possible? How? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no notion of extending elements in Relax NG. But you can use a definition in multiple places. For instance, the following schema defines a `personLike` structure (i.e. something which is "person-like"). Then this `personLike` definition is used for `PERSON` elements and `EMPLOYEE` elements.

```
start = (person | employee)+

personLike =
    attribute name { text },
    attribute city { text }

person = element PERSON {
    personLike
}

employee = element EMPLOYEE {
    personLike,
    attribute company { text }
}
```